# Why is there no $S_1$ and $S_2$ partition $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ with some conditions?

Tags: number-theory

For even integer $n\geq6$, let $S_1\cup S_2=\{1,\cdots,n\}$, $S_1\cap S_2=\varnothing$, $\vert S_1\vert=\vert S_2\vert$.

Why does not such $S_1$ and $S_2$ exist if $\prod S_1-\prod S_2=2$?

I obtained $pm\in S$ iff $pm'\in S$ with a prime $p$ and small integers $m$ and $m'$.

Also, one of $S_1$ and $S_2$ has exactly one even number but not other even numbers.

I don't know what I should do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\ge12$, then one set contains all the multiples of 3, including $6$ and $12$, so it also contains all but one of the even numbers.  That is too many.

Comment: You still have $n=6,8$ and $10$ to go